# how to add a cookbook with no recipe to runlist in chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, cookbook

I am trying to learn `chef` and `cookbooks`. All `cookbooks` I seen have a `recipe`. But this one [ruby_rbenv](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ruby_rbenv) have no recipes in source code. So in that case how can I use this?

I tried adding `ruby_rbenv::system_install` to `runlist`. But showing `error` that it cant find `system_install` in cookbook `ruby_rbenv`. Similarly if I try adding just `ruby_rbenv` to `run_list` it shows cant find `default` recipe error.

Could some one tell me how to do it in this case?

Here is the chef repo am working with now [my repo](https://github.com/flyingboy007/basic-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t add it to your run list. That is what we call a “library cookbook”, one that only exists to be depended on by other cookbooks so they can use the custom resources it defines.

Comment: so i create a custom cookbook like a wrapper for this one. right?

Comment: Yep, you would use it in a wrapper-style or application-style cookbook.